# Обращение к тексту, введённому в поле формы

Tags: html, jquery, form, input

Подскажите, будьте добры. Изучаю jQuery с недавних пор, так что, если это возможно, без специфических выражений и терминов.
Суть в следующем: сделать так, что-бы ссылка с кнопкой (к прим. "Найти") получала (приобретала) ссылку в зависимости от введённого в поле формы текста.

```
<form class="search-field__search-form">
<input class="search-field__input" type="search" placeholder="">
<button class="search-field__button" name="button-search">Найти</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('.search-field__button').on('click',function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var text = $('.search-field__input').val();
  console.log(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="search-field__search-form">
  <input class="search-field__input" type="search" placeholder="">
  <button class="search-field__button" name="button-search">Найти</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Отлично, премного благодарен за оперативность! 
То бишь в данном случае введённый пользователем в форму поиска текст хранится в переменной text, да?

Answer (score 1):

Вот только на js

```js
function qsa(e)
{return document.querySelectorAll(e)
}
qsa('.search-field__button')[0].onclick = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var text = qsa('.search-field__input')[0].value;
  console.log(text);
}
```

```html
<form class="search-field__search-form">
  <input class="search-field__input" type="search" placeholder="">
  <button class="search-field__button" name="button-search">Найти</button>
</form>
```